# Node.js HTTP server - how to combine static file server (like Trailer) with a URL router (like clutch)?

Tags: node.js, static, routes

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I'm starting to love the idea of server-side javascript.

I'm trying to create a web server that on one hand will serve static files with a module such as [Trailer](https://github.com/tylermwashburn/Trailer) and a URL router such as [Clutch](https://github.com/clement/clutch), and I'm seem to miss the point.

From the modules I see for Node.js there isn't such a simple library, there is Connect and Express, but they are a bit monolithic for me at this point, and I'm looking for something that I could define a static file server, and on top of that attach dynamic URL routing.

Any help/links/articles would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can't. `Clutch` nicely returns a function you can pass into `http.createServer` but `Trailer` does not. Do you have a good reason not to use connect/express ?

Comment: @Raynos Not familiar with them, and I'm using node 0.5 on windows so I'm still having wet feet trying to understand how it all works, and Connect/Express don't work on 0.5, 0.4 and 0.6 only.

Comment: Is there any other static file server that could work with something like Clutch?

Comment: [`connect-static`](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-static.html). Seriously though, use 0.4. It'll make your live easier.

Comment: 0.4 is linux only. 0.5 is an unstable build which has unstable windows support. You can try using `connect-static` on windows, if it breaks then debug/fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it looks that it's not possible to do what I want with Clutch and Trailer, so I'm trying to play with [Node-Paperboy](https://github.com/felixge/node-paperboy) that acts as a static file server but also has callbacks that could be used to intercept specific URLs and play with the `request` object (unlike Trailer).